# Bad ids with insert on a table in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, rdbms

i have a table with this sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "TEST"."TEST_SEQ" MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 301 CACHE 20 NOORDER NOCYCLE ;
```

In this table, when i launch many insert, i see that there is this situation :

```
insert n.1, creates row with id 301

insert n.2, creates row with id 304

insert n.3, creates row with id 305

insert n.4, creates row with id 302

insert n.5, creates row with id 303

insert n.6, creates row with id 306
```

it seems that in a random manner happens id jump and then the system " fills " the id left and then resume all normal

Thank you for the response

Comment: this is as expected.  The DB engine will multi thread the insert statements Some threads will be processed sooner than later in your list.  So they will not always go in the order you've provided.  Additionally depending on the insert, a record may be locked and the engine has to wait for that lock to be removed; while others could proceed.  Thus again an earlier insert gets a higher ID.  You may even see gaps as others using the system also perform inserts which get processed before your set is complete.

Comment: What does "launch many inserts" mean?  Assuming that you are spawning many different threads each of which has a separate database session, then whatever method you are using to get the number in "n.<<number>>" is not synchronized with the database request to get the `nextval` from the sequence.

Comment: I explained bad; the insert takes place in different transactions and in different day times, not part of the same transaction and in the all procedure that one of they are launched, this is only this table that have this problem. The attribute "NOORDER" could be the cause?